# How to do sibling selectors with Styletron or other CSS-in-JS frameworks?

Tags: reactjs, styletron

How can I translate this (LESS):

```
.urlBox {
    background: #ddd;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;

    + .urlBox {
        margin-top: 5px;
    }
}
```

To [Styletron](http://styletron.js.org/)?

So far I've got this:

```
const UrlBox = styled('div', {
    background: '#ddd',
    borderRadius: '5px',
    padding: '5px',
});
```

But I can't figure out how to do the sibling selector (`+`).

Comment: I don't think this is [possible](https://github.com/rtsao/styletron/issues/27) with Styletron at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

In [JSS](http://cssinjs.org/) we have [nested](http://cssinjs.org/jss-nested) syntax, which is similar to less/sass.